# Hola alguien sabe como hacer en Oracle pruebas declarando variables?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

alguien sabe como hacer en Oracle pruebas declarando variables y usándolas en consultas para posteriormente pasarlos a un SP?? En SQL Server comenzaba a declarar variables con declare @ejemplo. Pero en oracle no sé como hacerlo SIN hacer una función o procedimiento, solamente haciendo pruebas

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. La mejor forma de explicarnos lo que intentas hacer es con código de ejemplo. Qué es lo que hacías en SQL Server e intentas hacer en oracle? muéstranos un código de ejemplo para saber cómo ayudarte

Comment: Hola `@Elprogramador`. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Es importe lo que menciona @Alfabravo. Además, te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda.

Comment: declare variable int 

set variable = select id top 1 from VIP

select nombre from CLIENTES c
inner join TIPOCLIENTEt on t.idTipo = c.idTipo
where c.tipo = variable

Comment: Gracias el comentario de arriba fue un ejemplo de como hago consultas en SQL haciendo pruebas, en Oracle tengo que crear a fuerza un SP o procedimiento para poder hacer eso. O al menos no he encontrado como hacer esas pruebas en Oracle SIN crear un procedimiento o SP, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En Oracle se denominan variables "bind".

desde SQLPlus o en SQL-Developer se define la variable y se le asigna un valor

```
define  mi_variable  number

exec :mi_variable:=20
```

luego en la consulta donde requiera la variable se precede por el caracter "dos puntos" como en:

```
select *
from EMPLOYEES
where department=:mi_variable
```